# Asp.net to Excel but no grid / Lines in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I generate an excel file using the following code but I don't see any grids or lines in the excel file. I have my data but no lines. Any idea how to get the lines/regular grid?

```
Table oTable = new Table();
//Add data to table.

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="test.xls"");
Response.Charset = "";
this.EnableViewState = false;
System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter(oStringWriter);
oTable.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Can someone please help!?

Comment: You are generating an HTML file and delivering it with an Excel extension and MIME type. Don't do that. Generate a real Excel file using a dedicated library, such as Office XML SDK, EPPlus, or NPOI.

Answer (score 1):

You can see grid lines in Excel if you add a `Border` attribute to the Table:

```
Table oTable = new Table();
oTable.Attributes.Add("Border", "1");
```